# Use dynamic sum range and criteria range in SUMIFS

Tags: excel, sumifs

I'm using `SUMIFS` to calculate sales revenue of product X over a period of time. The problem is that all the sum range and the criteria ranges are dynamic since sales reps will add more rows to record new sales everyday. My formula looks like this:

```
=SUMIFS(Revenue!I5:I24,Revenue!F5:F24,"Product X",Revenue!B5:B24,">="&B3,Revenue!B5:B24,"<="&C3)
```

The starting row is row 5, and the last row that currently has data is row 24.
Revenue is the worksheet that contains the data. In this worksheet, column I is the revenue, column F is the product name, column B is the date that the revenue is recorded. B3 and C3 are the start and end date of the period.

When a sales rep records a new revenue, the last row that has data will become row 25, so my formula won't count it in. I tried to replaced 24 with 1000 hoping that it would count when new data was added beneath, but it returned `#VALUE`.

**What should I do?**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Declare 3 dynamic ranges and use their names in your formula.

```
=IFERROR(SUMIFS(revenueI,revenueF,"Product X",revenueB,">="&B3,revenueB,"<="&C3),"")
```

---

Adding the names: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to open the name manager and then enter the 3 names

Name: `revenueB`

RefersTo=

```
OFFSET(Revenue!$B$5,0,0,COUNTA(Revenue!$B$5:$B$1048576),1)
```

Name: `revenueF`

RefersTo=

```
=OFFSET(Revenue!$F$5,0,0,COUNTA(Revenue!$F$5:$F$1048576),1)
```

Name: `revenueI`

RefersTo=

```
=OFFSET(Revenue!$I$5,0,0,COUNTA(Revenue!$I$5:$I$1048576),1)
```

1048576 is for the max number of rows in more recent versions of Excel. Adjust to the total number of rows for your Excel version.

---

Wrap in an `IFERROR` in case of errors e.g. if named ranges are off different length.